# Retrieving data from xml file created by xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, vbscript

Not sure if the title makes any sense, but I need to read an XML document and retrieve the data created by an XSL XPath query.

The XML is located [here](http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputCapability/PUB_GenOutputCapability.xml) and the XSL [here](http://reports.ieso.ca/docrefs/stylesheet/GenOutputCapability_HTML_t1-1.xsl). If that's not possible, I'm assuming that I'll have to write the XPath query manually. So my question is, since XSL already generates the total, any way to parse it out of the XML file?

Thank you

Comment: You definitely want do boil that down to the minimum code size that shows your concrete problem. I may be able to help but I will not even begin to look at several hundred lines of XML and XSL code.

Comment: I don't understand the calculation you are trying to make. I'm almost certain what you are describing is possible but I can't help you without a clearly definition of your end goal.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you are asking how to take the totals generated by the XSLT.

I see 2 options:

1. Reverse engineer the XSLT - try understanding it and produce your own XSLT that calculates the totals you want. Copy the logic from the existing XSLT
2. Do second XSLT transformation on existing XSLT - take the result of the current XSLT and write your own XSLT that takes the interesting parts from it. For this you need XSLT command line tool.